# Javascript with Ajax refuses to work under firefox and IE9 but doing fine with chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, internet-explorer-9

Iam trying to figure out after solving quite a few css problems why a javascript doesnt respond under IE9 and Firefox. The script is quite simplistic still .. no luck !! It is simple an email validation that uses rsv.js by Benjamin Keen and ajax to push data to a php "sign-up" function on a different file. Chrome does this gloriously.. IE no matter what version and firefox, DO NOT.
**Any ideas pls pls??**

Here is the script that occupies an area between the head:

```
        function sign_up(email) 
        {
        var rules = [];
        rules.push('required,NewsletterEmail,Your Email is necessary for the newsletter!');
        rules.push('valid_email,NewsletterEmail,The Email is Invalid');
        if (rsv.validate(document.getElementById('newsletter'), rules)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'scripts/sign-up.php',
                data: 'email='+document.getElementById('NewsletterEmail').value,
                success: function(data){ $('#result').html(data); }
            });
        }
    }
```

**The form that is validated**

```
<form id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
<input class="email" id="NewsletterEmail" name="NewsletterEmail" value="Email" 
type="text" /><a class="btn" onclick="sign_up(NewsletterEmail.value);">SubmitNow</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, well the problem is that you are relying on a particularly bizarre, imho, feature of Chrome. Chrome takes all DOM elements with ids, and stores a reference to them in the global scope, accessible by name.

So when you write `NewsletterEmail.value`, Chrome goes and gets the value of the element with id `NewsletterEmail`. If you want it to work in other browsers, change it to the standard:

```
document.getElementById('NewsletterEmail').value
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think relying on onclick is a good idea when you have jQuery. Try this !

```
$("#newsletter").live("submit", function() {
    var rules = [];
    rules.push('required,NewsletterEmail,Your Email is necessary for the newsletter!');
    rules.push('valid_email,NewsletterEmail,The Email is Invalid');
    if (rsv.validate(document.getElementById('newsletter'), rules)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/sign-up.php',
            data: 'email='+document.getElementById('NewsletterEmail').value,
            success: function(data){ $('#result').html(data); }
        });
    }
  return false;
 });
```

Or maybe

```
$(".btn").live("click", function() {
alert("dalsjdsa");
var rules = [];
rules.push('required,NewsletterEmail,Your Email is necessary for the newsletter!');
rules.push('valid_email,NewsletterEmail,The Email is Invalid');
if (rsv.validate(document.getElementById('newsletter'), rules)) {
    alert("hemesh");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'scripts/sign-up.php',
        data: 'email='+document.getElementById('NewsletterEmail').value,
        success: function(data){ $('#result').html(data); }
    });
}
 return false;
});
```

Hope it helps you.
I assume that you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```
href="javascript.void(0)"
```

on the

```
<a>
```

tag

Comment: Something like that ?   <a href="javascript.void(0)" class="btn" onclick="sign_up(NewsletterEmail.value);">Εγγραφη</a></form>  cause isnt working :(

Comment: Error in IE9 and Firefox: "NewsletterEmail is not defined"    what the ...?

Comment: Try document.body.NewsletterEmail

Comment: onclick="sign_up(NewsletterEmail.value) Error in this line  'NewsletterEmail' is undefined